# Dropdown option not showing in the UI if data has "&" sign

Tags: html, angularjs, user-interface, html-select

Here is a sample data for my dropdown selection:

```
[
{
 "value":"test",
 "name":"test name"
},
{
 "value":"test2",
 "name":"test & name"
},
]
```

Here is the HTML code which displays the selection for the dropdown field:
[image]

for some reason, UI is not displaying the option if it has the "&" symbol in it. Any idea how to fix this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using HTML character entity may help, which means replace `&` with `&amp;`

Comment: i tried this but it doesnt work since the character entity still has the "&" sign

Comment: Have you tried JSON character entity? Like"\&"